# Displaying error message on other part of page using jQuery Validate and ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` and `jQuery validate`.

I have the following `HTML` markup:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ChangeIncidentNumber)
<button id="verifyButton" type="button">Verify</button>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ChangeIncidentNumber)
```

`verifyButton is just a button` and **NOT** a submit button.  When clicked it gets data from the database and populates the textbox with it.  I need a required message to display when the user clicks the button and nothing is entered into the textbox.

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#searchForm").validate({
          rules: {
               ChangeIncidentNumber: "required"
          },
          messages: {
               ChangeIncidentNumber: "Required"
          }
     });

     $('#verifyButton').click(function () {
          $('#searchForm').valid();
     });
});
```

If the textbox is empty and I click the button then the error message is displayed between the textbox and button.  I would like it to display on the right hand side of the button.  Not sure if it is possible, but can I use the element generated by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` to display the message?

Answer (score 0):

If you have form and you defined `form-id` then you can directly set `validation` on form submit , no need to define function on verify button click.

When you will submit form it's automatically check for validation.

**For displaying message on right side :**

```
<style>
label .error{
   float:none;
   display:block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I need this button click. Did you read the question? This is an additional button on the page to the submit button.